# pulseaudio not monitoring any audio output (i.e., ProjectM cannot work properly)

Tags: sound, configuration, pulseaudio, output

I've got an Acer Aspire TimelineX 3830TG with LUbuntu 12.10. Sound is working ok with all programs, but ProjectM Visualization is not. In pulseaudio preferences i can choose the analog or digital output (being the digital the hdmi plug, i guess). When selecting the former (so i can hear music from the speakers) there are no output levels registered, neither in the volume controls nor in the playback meter, so ProjectM is doing nothing, although the sound is there. If i change the output device to the digital output everything is working fine.

Any suggestion?

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

My pulseaudio's configuration files became corrupt, so i opened a terminal and wrote

```
rm -r ~/.pulse*; pulseaudio -k
```

it worked like a charm

cheers

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the output monitor ProjectM was attempting to listen to was for some reason muted. I opened up `pavucontrol` (PulseAudio Volume Control), went to the Input Devices tab, chose "Monitors" from the "Show:" dropdown and made sure the monitor ProjectM was listening to was unmuted.

You can configure which monitor ProjectM is listening to either in that same volume control application on the "Recording" tab by clicking the dropdown across from the ProjectM row's title (left of its mute button), or directly in ProjectM by going to Settings on the menu bar and choosing "Pulse audio settings" and double-clicking the monitor corresponding with your output.